# $.post is not working

Tags: php, jquery

I am trying to post data to Mysql using jQuery $.post and php page. my code is not running and nothing is added to the mysql table. I am not sure if the path I am creating is wrong but any help would be appreciated.

jQuery location: f_js/tasks/TaskTest.js

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#AddTask").click(function(){
            var acct = $('#acct').val();
            var quicktask = $('#quicktask').val();
            var user = $('#user').val();

            $.post('addTask.php',{acct:acct,quicktask:quicktask,user:user}, function(data){
                $('#result').fadeIn('slow').html(data);
            });
        });

    });

</script>
```

addTask.php (runs the jQuery code)

```
<?php
include 'dbconnect.php';
 include 'sessions.php';

    $acct = $_POST['acct'];
    $task = $_POST['quicktask'];
    $taskstatus = 'Active';
    //get task Creator
    $user = $_POST['user'];
    //query task creator from users table
    $allusers = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$user'");
    while ($rows = mysql_fetch_array($allusers)) {
        //get first and last name for task creator
        $taskOwner = $rows['user_firstname'];
        $taskOwnerLast = $rows['user_lastname'];
        $taskOwnerFull =  $taskOwner." ".$taskOwnerLast;

    mysql_query("INSERT INTO tasks (taskresource, tasktitle, taskdetail, taskstatus, taskowner, taskOwnerFullName)
            VALUES ('$acct', '$task', '$task', '$taskstatus', '$user', '$taskOwnerFull' )");
    echo "inserted";
 }



 ?>
```

Accountview.php finally the front page

```
<html>
 <div class="input-cont ">
                                      <input type="text" class="form-control col-lg-12" placeholder="Add a quick Task..." name ="quicktask" id="quicktask">
                                  </div>
                                  <div class="form-group">
                                      <div class="pull-right chat-features">
                                          <a href="javascript:;">
                                              <i class="icon-camera"></i>
                                          </a>
                                          <a href="javascript:;">
                                              <i class="icon-link"></i>
                                          </a>
                                          <input type="button" class="btn btn-danger" name="AddTask" id="AddTask" value="Add" />
                                          <input type="hidden" name="acct" id="acct" value="<?php echo $_REQUEST['acctname']?>"/>
                                          <input type="hidden" name="user" id="user" value="<?php $username = $_SESSION['username']; echo $username?>"/> 
                                          <div id="result">result</div>
                                      </div>
                                  </div>
 <!-- js placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
    <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="f_js/tasks/TaskTest.js"></script>
    <!--common script for all pages-->
    <script src="js/common-scripts.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/gritter/js/jquery.gritter.js"></script>
 <script src="js/gritter.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script>
</html>
```

Update: After running firebug i found that the page was not running correctly due to a missing session_start() line. after adding the line, the issue is now resolved.

Comment: Dumping your code and saying "it doesn't work" doesn't really help us. What debugging have you done so far?

Comment: Where specifically does it fail?  You need to do at least *some* debugging here.  Is there an error on the JavaScript console?  Is the AJAX request being made?  Does it have the expected values?  What is the server's response?

Comment: Apologize for the question in advance, but how do i debugg the 3 files together. I am using sublimetext to create my pages (still learning) any other tools would be recommended.

Comment: this is the response i got using firebug

Comment: Found the issue, in my AddTask.php i hade include 'sessions.php' after removal it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

just change the ID of the input to acct and user.

```
<input type="hidden" name="acct" id="acct" value="<?php echo $_REQUEST['acctname']?>"/>
<input type="hidden" name="user" id="user" value="<?php $username = $_SESSION['username']; echo $username?>"/>
```

or change in the JS file

```
var user = $('#user1').val();
var acct = $('#acct1').val();
```

Comment: i changed to acct1 while i was testing, reverted back but still issue persist